# angular ng-click on list item not firing

Tags: angularjs

Still learning angular, I would like to tap on an item from a list and show alert with the name of the item that was tapped.
 In mainMenu.html ng-click is registered with the list element `ng-click="mainMenuSelection(item.name)`, but the `alert(name)` is not being called in controllers.js
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

[image]

I also noticed the Google Chrome Sources does not show the views folder which contains mainMenu.html as per the second image.
[image]

```js
//---app.js-----------------------------------------------
(function () {                                          
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('angApp', ['ngRoute'])                  
        .config(['$routeProvider', routeProvider]);     
})();

function routeProvider ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'views/mainMenu.html',
        controller: 'MainMenuCtrl'
    }).otherwise({      //home page
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });
}

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['angApp']);
});

//---controllers.js-----------------------------------------------
angular
    .module('angApp')                                                   
    .controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenuCtrl]);

function MainMenuCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/mainMenu.json').then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.menuItems = response.data;
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("http error");
        }
    )
    $scope.mainMenuSelection = function(item) {
        alert(item);
    }
}

//---headerCtrl.js-----------------------------------------------
angular
    .module('angApp')
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', HeaderCtrl]);

function HeaderCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "Tap left menu \u2630";
    vm.headerTitle = setHeaderTitle;

    function setHeaderTitle(title) {
        vm.title = title;
    }
}
```

```html
//---index.html-----------------------------------------------
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <base href="http://localhost:63342/an1/">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>

<main ng-view></main>

</body>
</html>

//---mainMenu.html-----------------------------------------------
<section class="mainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-click="mainMenuSelection(item.name)">
            <image src="images/{{item.image}}.png"></image>
            {{item.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Where are `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in your code?

Comment: Where are your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives?

Comment: ignore comments about `ng-controller` and `ng-app`. Your controller is clearly registered in the routing config and it is clear that you are also manually bootstrapping the app

Comment: ng-app manual bootstrap at end of app.js. ng-controller injected via $routeProvider in the same file.

Comment: try including `ngTouch` script and inject as module if tap isn't working properly. Does it work with mouse events?

Comment: Everything looks right, can you make sure that the click event is getting fired? Try `console.log(item)` to see if the clicks on your `<li>s` are registering.

Comment: 'console.log("whaever")' is not putting out any thing.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or plunker and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry I can not, there are nested html file and I do not know how to :( and not sure if putting up the whole code would help any,

Comment: Created a fiddle for you in the answer.

Comment: any luck on this one?

Comment: I never used github before so I am doing a lot of reading now ;) if "your" code works, then what does that mean to my project?

Comment: You can run my code (which is version your code actually:)) in your environment and see if you still encounter issue, if YES: it might be some wired environment problem (browser version, etc.); if NO, compare all files between your and mine code, and find the difference. GitHub has an option of downloading a .zip file, no need of understanding Git. (learning basics of Git and Node.js would be a great idea also;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my [version in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yaPwKDkVEQKXOR0MYbLY?p=preview). I was trying to follow your file structure.

Make sure that `<body ng-app="angApp">` is there, thats only one thing that I've added (I now it looks too trivial...)

**EDIT:** adding Git repo

[Git](https://github.com/OlegKonyk/angular_list) repo with working code => clone => `cd` to directory => `npm instal` = `npm start` => files will be served on `port:63342` (serving file using node sever in order to replicate environment where issue is happening)

Comment: That did not fix it :(, what good does it do over the manual bootstrapping as shown at end of app.js? and OH, even ng-app="angApp" on the html tag does not fix it as well.

Comment: Could you try to add `$parent` in `mainMenu.html` => `ng-click="$parent.mainMenuSelection(item.name)"`?

Comment: unfortunately, that did not fix it either.

Comment: Do you actually see expected list, is it getting built in the DOM?

Comment: I see that :) What is the content of `headerCtrl.js`, nothing interferes there? This is extremely interesting, since everything looks fine....

Comment: 'headerCtrl.js' added to post.

Comment: Whenever you got a chance, would you clone this repo: https://github.com/OlegKonyk/angular_list.git I've putt all your code together. Clone it, cd to directory, and do `npm start` to start serving on `port:63342`, go to link `http://localhost:63342/an1/#/list`. I tested it in different browsers, works fine...

Answer (score 2):

I created a fiddle with a working example close to what you want.
Obviously, I have a much pared down version for the sake of brevity.

http://jsfiddle.net/frishi/U3pVM/21624/

```
(function () {                                          
'use strict';

angular
    .module('angApp', [])                  
    .controller("MainMenuCtrl", MainMenuCtrl)
})();

function MainMenuCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{
    name:"Tom"},
    {name: "Harry"},
    {name: "Wiley"}
    ]

    $scope.mainMenuSelection = function(item) {
        alert(item);
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="angApp">
<section class="mainMenu" ng-controller="MainMenuCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-click="mainMenuSelection(item.name)">
            <image src="images/{{item.image}}.png" />
            {{item.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>

</div>
```

I used a hard-coded JSON array of objects.
I also don't bootstrap the app the way you do.

There is too little information that your question provides, as to what could be the fault. Follow the example as specified in the fiddle, and if that doesn't work, reply with more details.